# Nth occurrence of a character and if conditionals

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Let's say we have two strings (ULRs):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask 
https://web.whatsapp.com/

I need to write expression such as:

if after 3rd slash (/) is nothing or 3rd slash does not exists do

```
{
some operation
} else {
another action
}
```

Please help.

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(str);
        }

    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    //copying and removing https from the list

     List<String> list2 =  new ArrayList<String>();
          Collections.addAll(list2, stringArr);
          Iterator<String> iter = list2.iterator();
          while(iter.hasNext()){
              if(iter.next().contains(https))
                  // here you should copy https lines to another file. 
                  iter.remove();
          } 

          String[] stringArr2 = list2.toArray(new String[0]);



        for (int i = 0; i<stringArr2.length; i++) {
            //condition for pure domain names.
            //else the action below



            System.out.println(getDomainName(stringArr2[i]) + "," + stringArr2[i] + "," + "U" +"," + number_of_doc + "," + today);
        }




    }

    public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}





}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't split :

```
String link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ";
if (link.split("/").length >= 3 ) {
    System.out.println("CORRECT");
}else{
    System.out.println("NOT CORRECT");
}
```

**The idea is :** Split your String with `/` if the result is great or equal then 3 then your condition is correct, else not correct.

**Edit**

Or like @biziclop mention in comment you can use **`Guava's Splitter`** for example :

```
Iterable<String> result = 
        Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("/")).
                limit(4).
                split("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");

if (Lists.newArrayList(result).size() > 3) {
    System.out.println(Lists.newArrayList(result).get(3));
}else{
    System.out.println("NOTHING");
}
```

**Input**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.com
```

**Output**

```
questions/ask
NOTHING
```

Comment: If you use Guava's `Splitter`, you can even specify an upper limit to the number of tokens you get, so you can retrieve everything after the third `/` as a single string.

Comment: i see this is good idea @biziclop thank you, did you mean this `Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("/")).omitEmptyStrings().split("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")`

Comment: Almost, you just need to not call `omitEmptyStrings()`, and call `limit(4)` instead. This way the 4th element returned will be `questions/ask`. If you get less than 4 elements, you don't have 3 `/`s in your string.

Comment: thank you @biziclop for the information i appreciate it ;) i already edit my answer, if i'm wrong in something thank you to tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple regex:

```
    String url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/";

    if(url.matches("\\w+://(\\w+.\\w+)+(.\\w+)*/(.+)"))
        System.out.println("Correct URL");
    else
        System.out.println("Incorrect URL");
```